# Create array of strings from array of documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, shell, aggregation-framework

I am trying to unnest an array of documents into an array of strings, using MongoDB shell:

**What I have**

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "instructions": [
      {
        "field": "A"
      },
      {
        "field": "B"
      },
      {
        "field": "C"
      }
    ]
  }
```

**What I want to obtain**

```
{
     "id":1,
     "instructions": ["A", "B", "C"]
}
```

**What I tried**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$instructions"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "instruction": "$instructions.text"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "id",
      $addToSet: {
        instructions: "$instruction"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**What I obtain**

```
query failed: (Location40234) The field '$addToSet' must be an accumulator object
```

**Do you know what I am missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to go so far. Simply use `$map` to move one by one

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      instructions: {
        $map: {
          input: "$instructions",
          in: "$$this.field"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gg_MTwjRs0L)**

Comment: Suppose you need to practice unwind and group, then https://mongoplayground.net/p/K82gDoCfF3E this will help you. Before that please refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Answer (score 2):

No need to use $map, simply project your field like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      instructions: "$instructions.field"
    }
  }
])
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KRYroTryMvb)