# How to convert array of documents to array in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document similar to this:

```json
{
  "field1": "a",
  "field2": {
    "subfield1": "sa",
    "subfield2": [
      {
        "name": "abc"
      },
      {
        "name": "def"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want something like this:

```json
{
   "field1":"a",
   "field2":{
      "subfield1":"sa",
      "subfield2":["abc","def"]
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create array of strings from array of documents in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990628/create-array-of-strings-from-array-of-documents-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2):

Using `projection` into `find`:

```
db.collection.find({/*your find query*/},
{
  "field1": 1,
  "field2.subfield1": 1,
  "field2.subfield2": "$field2.subfield2.name"
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n07T0j4ae-9)

Using `aggregate`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "field1": 1,
      "field2.subfield1": 1,
      "field2.subfield2": "$field2.subfield2.name"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zMRhmMNZY-P)

Also you can add  `"_id": 0,` to not output the `_id`. Examples [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jRWk-AvQYo-) and [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R5duXW3LqPx)

Comment: But this doesn't give me output like this "subfield2":["abc","def"] instead gives me nested arrays and documents

Comment: Oops sorry, I forgot `"field2.subfield1": 1,`. Now is fixed. The output is the same as desired one: `"subfield2":["abc","def"]`

Comment: Like @sadsun, the first of these doesn't work for me (using `db.collection.find` with a projection argument) (even though I see it works in your mongoplayground.net link) it only works when I use `db.collection.aggregate` with a `$project` stage. I am on MongoDB version 3.6.6. Notice both these other answers use `aggregate`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70299227/1175496) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64021123/1175496)